# Memory usage on Creating a Travian like map and 441 Buttons on a page

Tags: memory, memory-usage, map

I'm creating A Map like Travian on Xamarin forms

My map is something like 5000*5000

The way I want to do that is to load part of the map (21*21) of the big map where the current village is the center of the 21*21 map but show a 7*7 map to user(Again current village center of it)

So when user scrolls the map, can see the other parts of loaded map(21*21) and when the user reached end of the scroll, The map reloads...

But my question is when I want to do that I need to have something like 440 Buttons(Each button each tile of the map) ... Is it uses too much memory ?

Edit : The example of the map[image]

Comment: There are several clever ways of solving this problem. 441 buttons are not two many. It might not be a good idea for other reasons. Could you show us this map?

Comment: Sure look at the question @CandiedOrange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an isometric map.  There are many ways to handle it.  But if you feel like using math to solve the problem here are a few projection formulas.

Given mouse clicks on the screen you can find the maps cords with:

```
map.x = (screen.x / TILE_WIDTH_HALF + screen.y / TILE_HEIGHT_HALF) /2;
map.y = (screen.y / TILE_HEIGHT_HALF -(screen.x / TILE_WIDTH_HALF)) /2;
```

Given map cords you can project to the screen with:

```
screen.x = (map.x - map.y) * TILE_WIDTH_HALF;
screen.y = (map.x + map.y) * TILE_HEIGHT_HALF;
```

How this math is derived can be seen [here](http://clintbellanger.net/articles/isometric_math/).

Since the map can be scrolled you will need to add the scroll x and y to these calculations.

[Here](http://bigspritegames.com/isometric-tile-based-game-part-1/)'s a fairly good introduction to isometric graphics.

Comment: And How can I capture where clicked by the usere?

Comment: Depends on what your developing in.  Search for "mouse click" and "mouse down". along with your development environment.